# Multiple pivottable creation using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Im just starting to use [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) Lib to create "complex" workbooks via C#, and i just ran into some trouble while trying to create two pivot tables.

The first one creates fine, but when i try to create the second one it doesnt throw any exceptions but when i try to open the worknook using excel it says

> "Excel found unreadable content in 'myworkbook.xlsx'. Do you want to
> recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this
> workbook, clickYes"

And when i press 'yes':

> Repair log ->
> Removed Feature: PivotTable report from /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable2.xml part (PivotTable > view) Removed
> Records: Workbook properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)
> Repaired Records: Workbook properties from /xl/workbook.xml part
> (Workbook)

Here's the code that i build:

```
CreatePivotTable("Pivot1", "Pivot1", rng1);
CreatePivotTable("Pivot2", "Pivot2", rng2);
    public void CreatePivotTable(string pivotSheet, string pivotName, ExcelRangeBase srcRange)
    {
        if (m_wb.Worksheets[pivotSheet] != null)
            m_wb.Worksheets.Delete(pivotSheet);

        var ws = m_wb.Worksheets.Add(pivotSheet);

        var pivot = ws.PivotTables.Add(ws.Cells["A1"], srcRange, pivotName);            

    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was wrong and i didnt put it in my question was that i was reopening the workbook on step before, like this:

```
    CreatePivotTable("Pivot1", "Pivot1", rng1);
    Save();
    CreatePivotTable("Pivot2", "Pivot2", rng2);

    private void Save()
    {
        m_writer.Save();
        m_writer.OpenWorkbook ();
    }
```

And since the save method of epplus closes the workbook, the program lost some sort of reference or just got lost with some info.

In short, to use epplus correctly, you should write everything u need before saving and closing the workbook, its not good to reopen.

Thank you.